# How to redirect from domain to same domain but one difference using .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, server

I have very little knowledge about `.htaccess` and redirects. Is there a way to redirect every page of a website from `domain.com/page_1` to `domain.com/en/page_1`? This to happen for every page. If I have `domain.com/page_2` to redirect to `domain.com/en/page_2` and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this negative lookahead based rule in site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(?!en/)(.+)$ /en/$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

`(?!en/)` will match everything except a URI that starts with `/en/`

Comment: Thanks you very much for the answer and the explanation.

Comment: There seems to be some problems though. When I go to `domain.com` it goes to `domain.com/en/index.html.var`. Can you help me with this. I also removed the code from `.htaccess` but same thing is happening. Also when I go to `domain.com` it goes to `domain.com/en`. How to prevent that?

Comment: I've cleared the cache. The same thing is happening, also says page not found on title of page, even though the page is displaying.